# Monster attack is not randomising right

Tags: python, pygame, random

I have a code that I've been messing around with and the monster attack (monster.ma)
isn't randomising after the first time it's called upon (elif statement). I've tried to make it a tuple since they are immutable but it doesn't randomise after the first time. I was told to make a class and that's what I have done but it still doesnt work right. My attack variable (att) works right, but monsters' attack gets stuck. I know I can code the monster's attack into the elif statement, but I want to be able to just call upon it when needed.

```
import random

class monster():
    hp=50
    ma=random.randint(5, 20)
    xp=random.randint(15, 30)
a=1
exp=0
while a==1:
    if monster.hp<=0:
        exp+=monster.xp
        print"you have killed the monster"
        print("you get, "+str(monster.xp)+" exp from monster"
              "you now have, "+str(exp)+" exp")
        break
    elif monster.hp>=0:
        print"swing your sword"
        att=random.randint(5, 15)
        monster.hp-=att
        print"you do, "+str(att)+" damage to monster"
        print"monster does, "+str(monster.ma)+" damage to you" #<----------------here
```

Answer (score 6):

It's only randomized the first time because you're only calling the random function one time (when you create the monster object). When you have `ma=random.randmint(5, 20)` in your class then you are creating that variable with a random amount at that time, but you are not altering it. In order to get a random value every time you need to reset the value every time you perform an attack. Notice how you do this when you set `att`; you need to do it the same way with `monster.ma`.

If you want to be able to generate a random attack, you  need to create a method to do it. Something like this in your monster class:

```
def get_attack():
    return random.randomint(5, 20)
```

Should work whenever you call monster.get_attack(). Note however that it's generally a bad idea to use hard coded "magic numbers" like this. It would be a good idea to define a monsters attack stats as members of the monster class. It seems like you're making monster a class because you read somewhere that it should be a class and not because you're going for an object oriented structure. Read up on object oriented programming

Comment: Why not also encourage him to use `minDmg` and `maxDmg` constants instead of hardcoded 5's and 20's

Comment: Actually I did consider that but opted for the simplest answer since outlining how to make a properly constructed monster class seemed out of the scope of answering why random damage doesn't work right. Perhaps some suggestions would be good anyway, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very rusty with python, but usually what you want to do is create new monsters.

For example,

class monster():
    def **init**(self):
        self.ma = random.randint(5,20)

or something. That way, you can create new monsters with m = monster() and then use their attack. I'm not sure this is perfectly correct, but it should help.